# ¿ "parsererror" SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

[image: Primera imagen]

[image: segunda imagen]

No dejo de conseguir este mismo error, he investigado al respecto y parece que estoy enviando como html... algo? El concepto no me termina de quedar claro en las demás respuestas que se han encontrado con el mismo problema

```js
<?php 
include_once 'header.php';
?>

<script>
       $(function() {
        $(document).on('click', '#delete-btn', function (e) {
         e.preventDefault();

         var obj = {  
   'id-delete': $('#id-delete').val().trim(),
   'id-delete2': $('#id-delete2').val().trim(),
         };


         $.ajax({
          url: 'back_delete.php',
          method: 'POST',
          data: obj,
          success: function ( respuesta ){
           alert( respuesta.mensaje );
                                    window.location="index.php";

          },
          error: function( e, err, error ){console.log(e, err, error);}
             //Añadimos un nodo de error, por si pasa algo en el servidor, esto lo vamos a ver en la consola de depuración
            
          
         })
        });
       })
</script>


<div class="main-wrapper"> 
     

   <form class="signup-form"  method="POST"> 
   <h2>Eliminar Cuenta</h2>
   
   <input id="id-delete"type="text" name="id" placeholder="id" required> </input>

   <input id="id-delete2"type="text" name="id2" placeholder="confirme id" required> </input>
   

   <button id="delete-btn" type="submit" name="submit" value="eliminar"> 
   Eliminar
   </button>
   

</form>

<?php 
include_once 'footer.php';
?>
```

Y este es mi backend

```js
<?php
session_start();
include_once 'conexion.php';

$repuesta = array();
// la transformo en un array osea que pueda guardar multiples valores en una misma variable



if ( $_REQUEST['#id-delete'] !==  $_REQUEST['#id-delete2'] )
{
 $respuesta['mensaje'] = 'Id incorrecta';
}

else

{

$id_delete = $_REQUEST['id-delete'];

 $sql = "DELETE * FROM Usuario WHERE id = '". $id_delete . "'";
 mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
 // $sql = "UPDATE Usuario SET nick = '". $nicknuevo. "' WHERE id = '".$_SESSION['id'] . "'";

 if (mysqli_affected_rows($conn) > 0) 
 {
  $respuesta['mensaje'] = 'Se elimino con éxito';
 }

 else
 {
  $respuesta['mensaje'] = 'No hubo cambio en la tabla';
 }

}

header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode($respuesta);

?>
```

**EDIT: Solucionado**
Gracias a la mejor respuesta que seleccione, revise atentamente y me di cuenta de que yo tenia **if ( $_REQUEST['#id-delete'] !== $_REQUEST['#id-delete2'] )** en mi backend pero debía ser **if ( $_REQUEST['id-delete'] !== $_REQUEST['id-delete2'] )** ya que no puedo requerir el "#id-delete" ya que nunca  envie  un valor con ese nombre, si no que lo envie como 'id-delete', como se puede ver en mi formulario **'id-delete': $('#id-delete').val().trim(),** ahora ya no tengo el error (aunque sigue sin eliminarme la tabla) pero el objetivo del tema se cumplió.

**EDIT2: Ya elimina**
La siguiente forma no era la correcta

```
 $sql = "DELETE * FROM Usuario WHERE id = '". $id_delete . "'";
```

En su lugar use esto, y funcionó.

```
   $sql = "DELETE FROM Usuario WHERE id = '". $id_delete . "'";
```

Comment: y que es lo que te retorna el backend? debugeaste la funcion error?

Comment: lo único que veo malo es el header que dice 'Content-type... pero deberia ser ' Content-Type

Comment: @LPZadkiel El error esta solucionado, edite el mensaje con la solución, todo gracias a junior  a quien seleccione como mejor respuesta. Por cierto, como debugeo la función error? Podría servirme para mas problemas como estos en el futuro, gracias.

Comment: muchos IDEs te dejan agregar puntos de interrupción a tu código javascript como visual studio, phpstorm, eclipse, etc. Y si no estuvieras usando un IDE aún así puedes debugear en el mismo navegador agregando puntos de interrupción en el código javascript dentro de los archivos con las herramientas de desarrollador (F12) como también hay extensiones para debbuging como ChromePHP. Hay varias alternativas y creo que tu debes buscar la que más te acomode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que php te esta enviando un error para poder ver el error coloca en el metodo success del ajax lo siquiente

```
success:function(respuesta){
  console.log(respuesta);
}
```

y poder solucionarlo desde el archivo php

PD: el error puedes verlo en la consola del navegador

Comment: Me dijo que el index de la linea 10 de mi back end no estaban definidos,  revise atentamente y me di cuenta de que lo tenia **if ( $_REQUEST['#id-delete'] !==  $_REQUEST['#id-delete2'] )** pero debía ser **if ( $_REQUEST['id-delete'] !==  $_REQUEST['id-delete2'] )**  ya que no puedo requerir el "#id-delete" ya que nunca lo envie con ese nombre, si no que lo envie como 'id-delete', como se puede ver aqui **'id-delete': $('#id-delete').val().trim(),** ahora ya no tengo el error (aunque sigue sin eliminarme la tabla) gracias !!